# How to add new application to run from command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

For example when you execute

```
c:\> notepad
```

then a new notepad window opens. How can I create a custom shortcut for my application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Executing `notepad` isn't a shortcut, it's just launching an executable by name.

To find this executable, the prompt makes use of the following two environment variables:

- `Path`, which by default contains the folder where `notepad.exe` is (usually `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe`)
- `PATHEXT`, which by default contains `.EXE` (and more common executable file extensions)

To see the content of those variables, you can execute `echo %Path%` or `echo %PATHEXT%`, or press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> key combination, then go to **Advanced system settings** and choose **Environment variables**. You can also change their value this way.

To create a *shortcut* for an executable that you can use in the prompt, you could for instance:

1. create a shortcut to your application (using the normal "create
   shortcut" context menu entry,
2. add `.lnk` in your `PATHEXT` variable,
3. and add the folder containing your shortcut in your `Path` variable (or move the shortcut in a standard location, such as `C:\Windows\System32`)

Comment: Thx, it work for me. This is good article about that http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2008/01/xxx-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html

Answer (score 3):

Most applications have an executable named as `C:\Program Files\<appname>\<something>.exe`. This isn't in the standard system path. This is because nothing happens if you type in f.e. `firefox`.

Your possibilities to fix that:

- extend your `PATH` with the needed directory. It isn't really good solution, because it extends the system path only for a single executable to be made reachable.
- you create wrapper, for example in `C:\Mariusz\bin\firefox.bat`, which stands only from this (example):

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox\Firefox.exe

Of course you can have in this `C:\Mariusz\bin` directory as many batch wrappers as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way, is to simply put the application in %systemroot% This is how Windows commands generally work for example. Ping.exe is in the %systemroot%\System32 and SysWOW64 or c:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 directory so that when you can `ping` or `ping.exe` you can ping remote servers or hosts.

Comment: I can't put there my application. I tried with shortcut but doesn't work

Comment: @Mariusz - Please provide more information then simply "I can't" what specific errors messages do you get?

Comment: Putting something in the system root folder would work (because this folder is included in the PATH environment variable) but it isn't a sensible solution - you don't want to clog up your \Windows folders with non-OS files.

Comment: @Ramhound it to big application, it isn't one exe file but about 600 files and folders

Comment: @CJM you are correct, one small file here or there is not an issue. However with the comment here from Mariusz... You don't want a full blown package there, ever.